# getting location via GPS on android with Processing

Tags: java, permissions, location, processing, android-gps

im working on a small app that needs access to GPS so that i can track my position.
However i pasted some code that i can use to check if it works. I will rewrite it later so that it can be adjusted but for now i just want to try it.
**BUT** when i execute the app all paramaters stay the way they were initialized.
I do have all permissions enabled and also GPS enabled. Even went outside to check if it works, but it will always stay the same.
after the app asks if i allow the app to use gps service everything is executed correctly. It returns positive for location tracking.

Here is the code: (it can also be found under here: https://github.com/codeanticode/processing-android-tutorials/blob/master/location_permissions/ex1_gps/ex1_gps.pde)

```
/*****************************************************************************************
 Android Processing GPS example

 Query the phone's GPS and display the data on the screen

 Rolf van Gelder - v 22/02/2011 - http://cage.nl :: http://cagewebdev.com :: info@cage.nl

 Check the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in Sketch Permissions!

 *****************************************************************************************/

// Import needed Android libs
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

// Set up the variables for the LocationManager and LocationListener
LocationManager locationManager;
MyLocationListener locationListener;

// Variables to hold the current GPS data
float currentLatitude  = 0;
float currentLongitude = 0;
float currentAccuracy  = 0;
String currentProvider = "";

boolean hasLocation = false;

void setup () {
  fullScreen();
  orientation(PORTRAIT);  
  textFont(createFont("SansSerif", 26 * displayDensity));
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  requestPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "initLocation");
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  if (hasPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")) {
    text("Latitude: " + currentLatitude + "\n" +
         "Longitude: " + currentLongitude + "\n" +
         "Accuracy: " + currentAccuracy + "\n" +
         "Provider: " + currentProvider, 0, 0, width, height);
  } else {
    text("No permissions to access location", 0, 0, width, height);
  }
}

void initLocation(boolean granted) {
  if (granted) {    
    Context context = getContext();
    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    
    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    hasLocation = true;
  } else {
    hasLocation = false;
  }
}

// Class for capturing the GPS data
class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    currentLatitude  = (float)location.getLatitude();
    currentLongitude = (float)location.getLongitude();
    currentAccuracy  = (float)location.getAccuracy();
    currentProvider  = location.getProvider();
  }

  public void onProviderDisabled (String provider) { 
    currentProvider = "";
  }

  public void onProviderEnabled (String provider) { 
    currentProvider = provider;
  }

  public void onStatusChanged (String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in the logs for errors?

Comment: there are no errors. Everything runs smoothly except its not getting the data. It recognizes that gps permissions exist and gps access is allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

- change the "0, 0" in `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);` to a "1000, 0" depending on how often you want to get your current position in this case: 1000 ms. Im not gonna talk about the second 0.
- also instead of using `NETWORK_PROVIDER` use `GPS_PROVIDER` to get your true GPS pos instead of networked pos.